# ANDROID ANDENGINE -- change sprite on action down

Tags: android, touch, andengine, sprite

I have in my app some sprites.
When I touch a sprite (in TouchEvent.isActionDown() ) , I need to change its image

How can I made this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with AndEngine, but by the looks of it, the `Sprite` class does not provide the functionality to change its image - or better said: texture. However, you might be able to accomplish your goal by using the [`TiledSprite`](http://code.google.com/p/andengine/source/browse/src/org/anddev/andengine/entity/sprite/TiledSprite.java) or [`AnimatedSprite`](http://code.google.com/p/andengine/source/browse/src/org/anddev/andengine/entity/sprite/AnimatedSprite.java).

The latter is an extension of the first, so you should be able to use a TiledSprite. It has `setCurrentTileIndex()` and `nextTile` methods that seem to allow you to swap out one texture region by another. You may need to modify your images into a format suitable for AndEngine though and obviously you will need a handle to the touched sprite.